# Conditional probability proof- answer check

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I am new in probability. Sorry if I am asking stupid questions. I have a simple question:

Proof that 
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

for P(A) and P(B) not equal to zero.

I have googled the answer which should be:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A ∩ B)}{P(B)}$$
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A ∩ B)}{P(A)}$$
$$P(A∣B)P(B)=P(A∩B)=P(B∣A)P(A) $$
Dividing both sides by P(B):
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

My question is that I have done something different and I what to know whether my answer is acceptable or not.

My answer:
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A ∩ B)}{P(A)}$$
$$P(B|A)P(A)=P(A ∩ B)$$

and
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A ∩ B)}{P(B)}$$
Substitute $P(A ∩ B)=P(B|A)P(A)$ in we have:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

This was actually one of my exam questions with 4 marks and I am just thinking how many marks am I going to get with my answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, only your teacher can tell you how points will be distributed.  However, your approach is correct, and I can't see any reason you should be docked for it.

Comment: I am thinking because I did not specify $P(A∣B)P(B)=P(B∣A)P(A)$ in my answer and it might be a flaw. If $P(A∣B)P(B)=P(B∣A)P(A)$, can I say  $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(B)}$?